# Multiple computers "sharing" to a single monitor

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, external-display

Going to do my best in phrasing this question, because I haven't been able to find a suitable answer online.

I am wondering if it's possible to have multiple computers have access to a single 4k tv.

Use case. I have multiple people in the office, each person has 3 monitors for their work. However, there are times where person A wants to share some info with everyone in the office. And instead of shouting out the info, it would be cool to have the ability to "drag" a window to the 4k tv, so the entire office sees it. We use OSX in the office exclusively right now.

The main idea is to have anyone in the office be able to "drag" any window from their computer to this shared tv space for the entire office to see.

Don't know if this is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a program that multiple people can edit, like a Google Doc?  You wouldn't even need the screen as long as everyone had the app running.  But if you still wanted it displayed, just have one computer running the display with the app up.  Anytime someone updated the app with new info, it would be displayed on the screen within a few seconds.

Comment: @techturtle We use slack currently, so it's possible to copy and paste something and have it sent to everybody. However the work is pretty time sensitive (seconds matter) so copy and pasting something into google docs, slack, etc isn't really viable 80% of the time, and copy and pasting info from HTML markup, the formatting get's screwed up.

Comment: I can't think of how you could have multiple computers literally sharing 1 screen to where you could drag a window from any computer and have it show up on the common desktop.  I can think of a couple ways you could use remote desktop or screen sharing apps (like RDP, VNC, and TeamViewer) to be able to be able to share everyone's screen simultaneously on the big TV and then switch which one is on top, but with a "seconds matter" issue, I'm not sure this would be fast enough.  Maybe a script attached to a hotkey could auto pop any given computer to the top...

Comment: I would think an HDMI switch might work, but you'd still have to change inputs on the switch, which might not be any faster than a "shared doc" situation.

Comment: This might be done with a KVM switch. See http://www.kvm-switches-online.com/mac-kvm-switches.html